# Check if activity is running from service of same package

Tags: android, service, android-activity, xamarin.android, task

This is more of a doubt. Currently, my code works fine, but I want to make sure I'm doing it the right way.

I have a service, which checks if the activity is running on the foreground. If it is, it sends a broadcast to the activity, so the activity updates some stuff on the screen.

I created an `IntentFilter` on the service:

```
com.harkdev.ServerStatus.SERVER_UPDATED
```

Here the service needs to know if the activity is on the foreground, so it uses the `IsActivityRunning()` method, which reads the running tasks from the `ApplicationManager`. This means that I need to set the `GET_TASKS` permission.

Being that both, the SERVICE and the ACTIVITY are on the same package, is there a better way to get this info?? And maybe try and avoid setting the `GET_TASKS` permission??

This is the code in my service:

```
if (IsActivityRunning()) {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(SERVER_UPDATED);
    SendBroadcast(localIntent, null);
}
```

The `IsActivityRunning()` Method:

```
public bool IsActivityRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) GetSystemService(ActivityService);
    IList<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.GetRunningTasks(1); 

    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo[0].TopActivity;
    if (componentInfo.PackageName == "com.harkdev.ServerStatus") 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

And this is the code in my activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ServerStatusCheckService.SERVER_UPDATED);
    _receiver = new ServiceBroadcastReceiver ();
    _receiver.Received += Receiver_Received;

    RegisterReceiver(_receiver, filter);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you're doing the wrong way to compare strings:

```
if (componentInfo.PackageName == "com.harkdev.ServerStatus")
```

It should be:

```
if ("com.harkdev.ServerStatus".equals(componentInfo.PackageName))
```

Second, if the service and the activity are in your app then I think the requirement to check for "same package" is not necessary.

To send information from the service to the activity, you can use [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) (available in API 3+):

- When starting your service from the activity, you create a `ResultReceiver`, put it into the intent which starts the service.
- In the service, extract the `ResultReceiver` and keep it. When you want to send information, use [`send()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html#send%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29).
- In the activity, for example in `onDestroy()` you can trigger a command to notify the service that the `ResultReceiver` is invalid and it should be removed.

---

*Edied*

For example:

- In your activity:

  ```
  // Global variable.
  private ResultReceiver mResultReceiver = new ResultReceiver() {

      @Override
      protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
          // Update the UI here...
      }
  }
  ```

  When you start the service:

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, TheService.class);
  // You can use different action names for different commands.
  i.setAction("REGISTER_RECEIVER");
  i.putExtra("ResultReceiver", mResultReceiver);
  i.putExtra("ResultReceiver_ID", hashCode());
  startService(i);
  ```

  And in `onDestroy()`:

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, TheService.class);
  i.setAction("UNREGISTER_RECEIVER");
  i.putExtra("ResultReceiver_ID", hashCode());
  startService(i);
  ```
- In your service:

  ```
  import  android.util.SparseArray;

  // ...

  private SparseArray<ResultReceiver> mReceiverMap = new SparseArray<ResultReceiver>();

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      if ("REGISTER_RECEIVER".equals(intent.getAction())) {
          // Extract the ResultReceiver and store it into the map
          ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("ResultReceiver");
          int id = intent.getIntExtra("ResultReceiver_ID", 0);
          mReceiverMap.put(id, receiver);
      } else if ("UNREGISTER_RECEIVER".equals(intent.getAction())) {
          // Extract the ResultReceiver ID and remove it from the map
          int id = intent.getIntExtra("ResultReceiver_ID", 0);
          mReceiverMap.remove(id);
      }

      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: What if i programmed the service to be executed by the AlarmManager? How would I handle the ResultReceiver?

Comment: @JuanuHaedo If there is no `ResultReceiver` registered in the service, then there is no running activity. So you don't need to check.

Comment: Maybe i should explain a little further how my app behaves.

First: My activity creates an Schedule. 
Second: This Schedule is Executed on the Service by the AlarmManager
Here comes the Tricky Part:

If The Service is executed and the Activity is running, I need to update the information on the activity screen, else, do nothing.

Comment: @JuanuHaedo I meant, when you start the activity, you can register a `ResultReceiver` with the service. If you start the service from an alarm, then nothing is registered. In the service you can use a `List` to keep all instances of the `ResultReceiver`. If the list is empty then there is no activity which is running in foreground.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother, but could you write some example on this?
I understand what you say, I just don't know how to implement it...

Comment: Oh thank you!
I understand this...
But as i previously said, the service is always started from the AlarmManager, and from there, I need it to check if Activity is running, and if it is update stuff on the screen...

Could I use the same code but instead of starting the service, create a PendingIntent and set it to the AlarmManager, and then from the service, use the receiver to see if the Activity who created it is running?

Comment: @JuanuHaedo I'm not sure  :-(  From the example you can always check the `mReceiverMap`, if it is empty then there is no activity running. You can always trigger a command to the service anytime.

Comment: Ha! I Finally figured out what you were saying.
I was having trouble understanding how the Services Work. 
I thought each INtent was a new Service Instance, but I see that they work as a Single Instance, so registering stuff in it, will work... Thank you!

Comment: what if the activity crash suddenly ?